# SQLAlchemy Primary Key from Unique and Primary Foreign Keys

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, reports and bids, with a one to many relationship where a report can have multiple bids. Simplified a report looks like this:

```py
class Report(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reports'
    
    dr_nbr = Column(CHAR(14), primary_key=True)
    header_trade = Column(VARCHAR(255), unique=True)
    bids = relationship("BidDetail", lazy="dynamic")
```

The bids table looks like this:

```py
class BidDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bids'
    
    report_id = Column(CHAR(14), primary_key=True)
    report_header_trade = Column(VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
                            [report_id, report_header_trade],
                            [Report.dr_nbr, Report.header_trade]),
                     {})
```

I have tried a few ways to import the two keys from reports and use as primary keys. I know that when I use primary foreign keys from another table I need to define a `ForeignKeyConstraint`, but when one foreign key is primary and another unique it doesn't work. Another thing I've tried (by researching similar questions on SO) is passing the two fields that are foreign keys to `__table_args__` as `UniqueConstraint`, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing and it also doesn't work.

How do I import two foreign keys in SQLAlchemy where one is a `primary key` and the other has a `unique` constraint?

Comment: The problem is that the referenced columns in reports table are unique separately. If you added a unique constraint covering both columns to reports, you should be able to reference them with a foreign key. Note that if you've first tried to create the tables without it, you might have a left over reports table hanging around in the DB.

Comment: I drop all tables before making changes to make sure that the tables are created fresh. Are you suggesting I make a `UniqueConstraint` in `reports` table and pass it as to `__table_args__`? Do I keep or remove the `unique` constraint for `header_trade` in that case?

Comment: and when a unique constraint is defined in reports then how do I import the two columns to bids?

Comment: `__table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(dr_nbr, header_trade), )` would be a solution. Whether or not you remove the individual unique constraint depends on what you're after. If you remove it, you can have pairs such as (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1). On the other hand if they're both separately unique and unique as a pair, you can't have duplicate values. When the unique constraint is properly in place in Report, your current implementation of BidDetail should work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help @ilja-everilä for answering the question in the comments. The right way to define the tables is:

```py
class Report(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reports'

    dr_nbr = Column(CHAR(14), primary_key=True)
    header_trade = Column(VARCHAR(255))
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(dr_nbr, header_trade),)
    contacts = relationship(
                    'Contact',
                    secondary='report_contact_link'
    )
    bids = relationship("BidDetail", lazy="dynamic")

class BidDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bids'

    report_id = Column(CHAR(14), primary_key=True)
    report_header_trade = Column(VARCHAR(255), primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
                            [report_id, report_header_trade],
                            [Report.dr_nbr, Report.header_trade]),
                     {})
```